How to serialize double to JSON without scentific notation Newtonsoft JSON.NET?
ASP.NET Core app uses Newtonsoft JSON.NET for serialization:
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

There is some model with property of type double:
public class SomeModel
{
    public double Number { get; set; } = 0.0000000100000000000000001234567;
}

And also this controller:
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/")]
    public SomeModel Index()
    {
        return new SomeModel();
    }
}

The result is json {"number":1E-08}.
The expected result is {"number": 0.0000000100000000000000001234567}. How can this be achieved?
I've already tried using FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal and creating new converter, but scientific notation remains.

Actually this is not related with Newtonsoft JSON.NET, the C# will render the 0.0000000100000000000000001234567 to 0e-08 , you could directly see it inside the  VS when using breakpoint, could you please tell me why you will use inside your model?

you have to specify format from beginning
this example should help you to understand and how to convert its also rounding:
void Main()
{
    var x = new SomeModel().Number;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(x.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float));

    var x2 = new SomeModel().Number2;
    Console.WriteLine(x2);
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(x2.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float));
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(new SomeModel().Number3.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float));
}

public class SomeModel
{
    public double Number { get; set; } = 0.0000000100000000000000001234567;
    public double Number2 { get; set; } = 0.0000000100000000000000001234567F;
    public decimal Number3 { get; set; } = 0.0000000100000000000000001234567M;
}

result would be
1E-08
0.00000001
9.99999993922529E-09
0.00000000999999993922529
0.0000000100000000000000001235

serialized
{"Number":1E-08,"Number2":9.99999993922529E-09,"Number3":0.0000000100000000000000001235}
