Reading Json number as a string
What I need:

Deserialize Json string to and object
Do some stuff
return it as a string at the end

What is the problem?
When Json has property like {"foobar" : 0.0000000000000000001}, it is converted as a number, but then as a string it is represented in scientific notation as 1E-19
Is there a way to read number from json as a string, or convert such a number later to exact same string, without any precision loss? Precision is not fixed and number in json can occur in any property.
Usage of Newtonsoft is preferable (if it's possible) over System.Text.Json
I've tried to

create Newtonsoft's CustomJsonConverter
use System.Text.Json.JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString
converting float to string
but any of this solutions didn't work
I couldn't find a way to treat any number value as a string, idk if it's even possible in such converter
This one I think works only one way, from obj to string, and this is not what I'm looking for
such a conversion didn't work because it lost a precision, or did "over precision" (0.00...01 was written as 0.00...0989919999 or smth like this), or added additional zeros at the end - depends what formatting I've used

Ideally I'd like to convert string like {"foobar": 21.37} to object with property foobar = "21.37" to be sure that any precision won't be lost after coverting between number/string
Minimal Reproducible Example
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var json = """
    [{
        "foobar1": 21.37000,
        "foobar2": 0.0000000000000000001000,
        "foobar3": 1.1000E-19,
        "aReallyBigInteger" : 1111199999999999999999999999999999999911111
    }]
    """;
var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);

Console.WriteLine(input);
/*
Expected result:
[
  {
    "foobar1": "21.37000",
    "foobar2": "0.0000000000000000001000",
    "foobar3": "1.1000E-19",
    "aReallyBigInteger": "1111199999999999999999999999999999999911111"
  }
]
Current Behavior:
[
  {
    "foobar1": 21.37,
    "foobar2": 1E-19,
    "foobar3": 1.1E-19,
    "aReallyBigInteger": 1111199999999999999999999999999999999911111
  }
]
*/


not very clear. The precision limitation is due to the internal representation of the number (i.e. a double). The string from/to doesn't limit the precision, unless some formatting scheme is used. However, I don't think any is used.

Have some test here: https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046048048048048048048048048048048048048048048048048048048049

Why do you care how the floating point number is represented in the json? Do you have reason to believe it loses precision during a serialization/deserialization roundtrip?

There is no way to do this with Json.NET.  JsonTextReader will parse JSON numbers to double, decimal, int or some other numeric type, then discard the original textual representation which is never made publicly available to callers.  You could try forking Json.NET and modifying JsonTextWriter to preserve the character representation of numbers, but I suspect it would be nontrivial.

Clients demands - at the end I need to show same string as it was at the beginning so when clients puts 0.0001 he want's to see later 0.0001 not 1E-5 (I'm returning string at the end)

It can, however, be done with System.Text.Json.  JsonElement and JsonNode preserve the underlying character representations of the JSON tokens so you when you write them back they will be unchanged.  Perhaps that would meet your needs?

@MarioVernari it does limit - simple test
double x = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
string xStr = x.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(xStr);
//it will return 1E-57
//it will not return  0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

@MatteoDelOmbra Is that exceeding the precision of double in the first place?

@dbc I've tried that but at the end it returned number, not a string still.  can you elaborate how to do that, maybe I've done smth wrong

a) this number cannot be represented as a double (it only supports 17 significant digits) b) 1E-57 and 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 is literally and exactly the same numeric value (just different representations, the same way that 0x10, 0o20, and 16 are the same number)

"at the end I need to show same string as it was" - then transmit as string ??

@MatteoDelOmbra - can you share a [mcve] then?  Of course the types double and decimal can't preserve numeric formatting but if you read into a JsonNode I believe it is remembered.

^^ And even if it doesn't: You could introduce a type that has a property for the numerical value and a separate property for the (enforced) string representation. Or Value and Format?

Here is a demo of JsonNode.Parse() preserving numeric formatting: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JHO53j.

Hmm, Shingo's answer was correct: Json.NET does preserve numeric formatting for properties declared as strings, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lwrvdv.  Of course they get written back as strings, with quotes.  I'm almost certain that that can't be done with a converter though, the serializer is using a private API to do it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"at the end I need to show same string as it was" then format it that way. There is a difference between a "number" and its representation. 0.00001 and 1E-5 are the same number but in different representations. If you (or your customer) likes represenation X, you yourself have to care, that the value is represented that way. The system has a certain default behaviour. If you don't like that, you have to override it ...

@derpirscher yes formatting this is my problem - I specified that and reading number as a string was just one of ideas how I think it can be resolved - if there is a way to format end string to look always same as input string then I'm ok with that

@dbc I've aded minima reproducible example
About Shingo's answer - this is kinda result I'm looking for, but I don't know the format of data that will be provided - such a number can occur in any property I just need to process it and return such numbered intact

@dbc about dotnetfiddle you provided - In a final json data are still numbers (without quotes) I am using other features of newtonsoft which I couldn't find in System.Text.Json (as iterating through all descendants) so usage of System.Json for me is acceptable only if I can change those numbers to strings, create Json string from it and then deserialize new json string using Newtonsoft

@dbc oh and regaring to you fiddle one again. In theory I think it should work if I add there NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString to serializer options, but It still gives numbers (not string in quotes) in output so I guess this option is not working at all

Do you need to deserialize to JToken or could you deserialize to a fixed data model?

@dbc No, I dont know what will be structure of data so I can't use fixed data model

MY SOLUTION
Smelly code but the one that worked for me.

deserialize json with System.Text.Json
serialize it with use of custom converter written by Groxan here back to json
New json can be deserialized using standard Newtonsoft and our numbers are already strings and are treated like ones.

Probably terrible efficiency but only one that meets my requirements.

I tried building a custom Converter class like the one shown below and used it to deserialize a JSON string containing numbers, and it seems to be returning the numbers as string without losing any precision. Please give it a try and let me know if it works.
public class NumberToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(decimal) || objectType == typeof(double) || objectType == typeof(float);
    }
    
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Float || token.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
        {
            return token.ToString();
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unexpected token type: {token.Type}");
    }
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}


I used it for such an example
var json =
@"[{
""foo"" : 0.1,
""bar"" : 1.00,
""baz"" : 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
}]";
But it returned false in CanConvert() as detected type was JToken

@MatteoDelOmbra you can't achieve that, unless you'll write your own JSON parser and using an "infinite precision" library as number handling. To me, that's a limitation of your clients, because the scientific notation in the JSON is fully legal: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

@MatteoDelOmbra - the JSON you've provided here in your comment is an array of objects while the one you mentioned in your question is a single object, so you'll need to adjust your class structure accordingly as per your client's requirements to parse it. Make the respective changes & this method will work perfectly fine for you.

@YashGupta  I run it as well with  var json = @"{ ""foo"" : 0.1, ""bar"" : 1.00, ""baz"" : 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 }"; but behavior is the same

this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78339575/how-to-serialize-double-to-json-without-scentific-notation-newtonsoft-json-net/78344123#78344123
